# Replace every odd or even occurrence of a pattern in a file

Tags: text-processing, sed, markdown

I want to replace either every odd or even occurrence of a pattern. Look at the following example:

```
$ echo aaaaa | sed -e 's/a/b/' -e 's/a/c/' -e 's/a/b/' -e 's/a/c/' -e 's/a/b/'
bcbcb
```

Is there some command that can do this more concisely? What I'm actually doing is converting `*`s into BBCode `[i]` and `[/i]` tags, so if there's a markdown-to-BBCode converter out there, I'd like to hear about it too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sed 's|\*\([^*]*\)\*|[i]\1[/i]|g'
```

Comment: Aah, for some reason I didn't think of group capturing, thanks a million (well... 25, anyway).